# Filter nested array in mongoDB with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to filter a multi-level nested array in MongoDB. The schema is as follows,

```json
    {
      "_id": "1234",
      "array1": [
        {
          "id": "a11",
          "array2": [
            {
              "id": "a21",
              "array3": [
                {
                  "id": "a31",
                  "status": "done"
                },
                {
                  "id": "a32",
                  "status": "pending"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The required output must filter **array3** with condition **status=done**. Which is the best possible method to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$map` to iterate `array1` and `array2`, use `$filter` to filter `array3`. Finally compare `array3` with empty array for document matching.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "array1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array1",
          "as": "a1",
          "in": {
            id: "$$a1.id",
            array2: {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$a1.array2",
                "as": "a2",
                "in": {
                  id: "$$a2.id",
                  array3: {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$a2.array3",
                      "as": "a3",
                      "cond": {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$a3.status",
                          "done"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "array1.array2.array3": {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EhjHVEl9P6u) for your reference.

Comment: The above query doesn't work. It returns all the elements in array3.

Comment: So you want the document to be found, with array3 containing only 1 element `"status": "done"`?

Answer (score 1):

Query

- almost the same as @ray query
- `$mergeObjects` allows us to not write the fields by hand($setField can be used also if mongoDB5+) (if instead of id you also have 10 fields, this will work without changing the query)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6265a9e28b39bcf74dae2759)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"array1": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$array1",
        "as": "a1",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$a1",
             {"array2": 
               {"$map": 
                 {"input": "$$a1.array2",
                  "as": "a2",
                  "in": 
                   {"$mergeObjects": 
                     ["$$a2",
                      {"array3": 
                       {"$filter": 
                        {"input": "$$a2.array3",
                         "as": "a3",
                         "cond": {"$eq": ["$$a3.status", "done"]}}}}]}}}}]}}}}}])
```

Comment: It's an good idea to use $mergeObjects

Answer (score 0):

i just asnwered the same question from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599962/9267467

the query is simply.
let me put my code here again because this is more deeper

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newArray: "$array1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "newArray.array2.array3.status": "done"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "newArray"
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/esRdBl8JvWG)