# mongodb use aggregate filter multi-level nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have an array：

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 1,
    list: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: 11,
        list: [
          [
            { id: 111, name: 111 },
            { id: 112, name: 112 }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 6,
    list: [
      {
        id: 62,
        name: 12,
        list: [ [ { id: 111, name: 111 } ] ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope filter the second-level list array，use command as follow

```
{
  $project: {
    id: 1, name: 1,
    list: {
      id: 1, name: 1,
      list: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$list.list',
          as: 'item',
          cond: { $eq: ['$$item.name', 111] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but not get the expected result. The complete filter code is as follows:

```
db.runoob.aggregate([{ $match: { $or: [{ 'name': 1, 'list.name': { $eq: 11 } }, { name: 6, 'list.name': { $eq: 12 } }] } }, { $project: { id:1, name: 1, 'list': { $filter: { input: '$list', as: 'item', cond: { $or: [{ $and: [{ $in: ['$$item.id', [11, 12]] }, {$eq: ['$$item.name', 11]}] }, { $and: [{ $in: ['$$item.id', [61, 62]] }, {$eq: ['$$item.name', 12]}] }] } } } } }, { $project: { id: 1, name: 1, list: { id: 1, name: 1, list: { $filter: { input: '$list.list', as: 'item1', cond: { $eq: ['$$item1.name', 111] } } } } } }])
```

Please help me, thanks ^_^

I have tried to use $unwind as follow

```
db.runoob.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$list' }, { $unwind: '$list.list' }, { $unwind: '$list.list.list' }, { $match: { $or: [{ 'name': 1, 'list.name': { $eq: 11 }, 'list.list.name': { $eq: 112 } }, { name: 6, 'list.name': { $eq: 12 } }] } } ])
```

but this command will destroy the structure

I hope keep the original data structure，or there are other ways to restore the structure after using $unwind

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the content of this article: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991025/filter-nested-array-in-mongodb-with-mongoose)

I have tried to write codes as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "name": 1,
          "list.name": {
            $eq: 11
          }
        },
        {
          name: 6,
          "list.name": {
            $eq: 12
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
      "list": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$list",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$item.id",
                      [
                        11,
                        12
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$item.name",
                      11
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$item.id",
                      [
                        61,
                        62
                      ]
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$item.name",
                      12
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      name: 1,
      list: {
        $map: {
          input: "$list",
          as: "item1",
          in: {
            id: "$$item1.id",
            name: "$$item1.name",
            list: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$item1.list",
                as: "item2",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$item2.name",
                    111
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "list": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$list",
          "as": "a1",
          "in": {
            id: "$$a1.id",
            name: "$$a1.name",
            list: {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$a1.list",
                "as": "a2",
                "in": {
                  id: "$$a2.id",
                  name: "$$a2.name",
                  list: {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$a2.list",
                      "as": "a3",
                      "cond": {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$a3.name",
                          1111
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

Both of these codes can get correct results.

Because my array nesting level will be very deep, whether there are other better options?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to keep the original data, you should `replica` the `field` before using `$unwind`. and after data found, remove the the `replica`

```
db.runoob.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newlist: "$list"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$newlist"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$newlist.list"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "newlist.list.id": {
        "$in": [
          111
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "newlist"
  }
])
```

[MONGO PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d_UgHneMCG6)

the operation `$match` can also be like below:

```
{
    "$match": {
      "newlist.list.id": 111
    }
}
```